# How can I connect to the AWS IAM API in a private VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to run Terraform in a private VPC using the AWS provider. Terraform [supports overriding various AWS endpoints](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/guides/custom-service-endpoints.html) and so I have been using [VPC Endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints.html) to expose relevant services in my VPC and overriding those endpoints in my provider configuration.

Unfortunately IAM is not supported by VPC Endpoints - I need this API to create some resource for example AWS roles, so how can I use this API in my private VPC from Terraform?

```
$ terraform -v
Terraform v0.11.13
+ provider.aws v2.17.0
```

Comment: Do you have to run Terraform from inside the VPC for creating these IAM resources? Does the VPC have to be absolutely private (eg no public subnets or NAT at all)?

Comment: It can reach the internet via another peered VPC, but I would prefer not to have to configure/support that - I feel there should be a way to access the API without requiring internet access

Comment: If the endpoint isn't available by VPC endpoints then no you need to be able to access the IAM endpoint over the internet or via a peered VPC that does have access to the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Cloudformation supports VPC endpoints. So you can make a Cloudformation template that creates the IAM resources. Then apply that cloudformation stack via terraform. Then do another Terraform module that refers to those resources as data sources.

Given the constraints of your problem, it is only possible to solve this indirectly.

Docs: [Terraform Docs for Cloudformation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudformation_stack)
[Docs for AWS Cloudformation VPC Endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-vpce-bucketnames.html)

Comment: Nice idea! You wouldn't be able to use IAM data sources directly either (not sure if that's what you were suggesting), but you could always just output what you need in the stack and reference it that way (including from a CloudFormation data source).